# How to aggregate list value due to field

Tags: apex, list

I have a query like this:
`List<MyCustomObj> myCustomObjList = [Select code, color, isSold FROM myCustomObj];`
and that's the result:

```
myCustomObjList =  [a1a, red, true],
                   [a1a, blue, false],
                   [a3u, red, true],
                   [bba, red, true],
                   [bba, blue, false],
                   [a3u, white, true]
```

I want to aggregate results due to a field like code, expected result:

```
list_a1a = [[a1a, red, true], [a1a, blue, false]]
list_a3u = [[a3u, red, true], [a3u, white, true]]
list_bba = [[bba, red, true], [bba, blue, false]]
```

How can I do this in Apex (without GROUP BY in the query) ?

Answer (score 2):

The thing that'll help you out here is a Map, specifically a Map with another collection nested inside. `Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>`

The idea is that you:

- declare the map outside of your loop
- perform your query and loop over the results
- inside the loop

  - check to see if your target field's value does not exist as a key in the map

    - if it doesn't, put the key into the map along with a new `List<Custom_Object__c>`
  - now that the target field is guaranteed to be in the map, you can simply `map.get(theKey).add(theRecord);`

Specifically checking that the key *doesn't* exist in the map (and putting a blank list into the map in that situation) allows you to omit the `else` that you'd otherwise have, as it makes adding a value to the nested list use the same code no matter whether it's the first item being added, the second, or the last item.

In a little more concrete terms, it's the difference between this:

```java
if(!myMap.containsKey(key)){
    myMap.put(key, new List<Custom_Object__c>{myRecord});
}else{
    myMap.get(key).add(myRecord);
}
```

and this:

```java
if(!myMap.containsKey(key)){
    myMap.put(key, new List<Custom_Object__c>());
}

myMap.get(key).add(myRecord);
```

Just a little bit less repetition and a little less typing. I happen to think that the second one is easier to digest, mentally, too.